# Error while parsing XML through OPENXML

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an XML of 55MB and is trying to shred it using OPENXML as it seems to be faster than normal XML shredding. The structure of XML is like this :

```
<DATA_EXPORT>
<HEADER>
    <RECDATE>
        <START>2011-03-16</START>
        <END>2012-02-10</END>
    </RECDATE>
    <SOME_COUNT>10288</SOME_COUNT>
    <QUESTION_MAP>
        <QUESTION>
            <SERVICE>OU</SERVICE>
            <VARNAME>UNIT</VARNAME>
            <QUESTION_TEXT></QUESTION_TEXT>
        </QUESTION>
                250 more nodes like <QUESTION> 
    </QUESTION_MAP>
</HEADER>
<SOMENODES>
    <SURVEY_ID>448817197</SURVEY_ID>
    <CLIENT_ID>58</CLIENT_ID>
    <SERVICE>OU</SERVICE>
    <RECDATE>2011-03-29</RECDATE>
    <DISDATE>2010-03-29</DISDATE>
</SOMENODES>
    :
    :
   1000s of nodes like <SOMENODES>
</DATA_EXPORT>
```

And I am using following query for getting the data out of the nodes

```
declare @xmlData varchar(max) = null
        ,@iDoc int  = null
        ,@xml xml = null

select @xmlData = cast(@xml as varchar(max))

    exec sp_xml_preparedocument @iDoc OUTPUT, @xmlData 

    select *
          ,getdate()
    from openxml(@iDoc, '//DATA_EXPORT/SOMEDATA', 2)
    with (
        surveyId        varchar(50)     'SURVEY_ID[1]',
        clientId        int         'CLIENT_ID[1]',
        [service]       varchar(50)     'SERVICE[1]',
        recieveDate     datetime        'RECDATE [1]',
        dischargeDate   datetime                'DISDATE [1]'
    )
    option (optimize for unknown)
```

I have wrritten this is stored procedure and am getting following error:

```
The XML parse error 0xc00ce562 occurred on line number 1, near the XML text "<".
Msg 6602, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_xml_preparedocument, Line 1
The error description is 'A declaration was not closed.'.
Msg 8179, Level 16, State 5, Procedure q_ImportSurveyMasterDetails, Line 81
Could not find prepared statement with handle 0.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Can anybody help me what is the error in line number as indicated by the error?? 
Also is there any better and faster way to shred a 55MB XML file??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume the Xml is well-formed, would you be able to open it in VS or SSMS? If the Xml has a declaration, check if there is some white space in front of it. Did you try using the `XQuery` syntax (mainly `nodes()` and `value()` functions)? Another option would be a Sql Clr stored procedure, but it involves more work.

Comment: I was able to open it in VS and checked if there is any special character in line 1. However there was no special character before starting of the tag.

Comment: Right, I was wondering why you use `@xmlData VARCHAR(MAX)` as argument for `sp_xml_preparedocument`, and not directly `@xml XML`. Could be that some characters get clobbered during the conversion because of the encoding?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. I dont know why I did that. That fixed the issue. However I am trying to use same query inside a merge statement.  But came across new problem it gives me error near option keyword. The error is `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'option'`. So my question is cant I use option keyword as I might have to shred xml of unknown size at times.

Answer (score 1):

Issue# 1: `The XML parse error 0xc00ce562 occurred on line number 1, near the XML text "<"`. 
Fixed by changing  @xmlData to @xml i.e. not converting it to varchar(max) just passing it as an xml. Thanks @dan radu for all your help.

Issue# 2: option keyword inside merge statement. It seems it cannot be used inside merge because merge statement is itself a single sql statement. It should be used at the end of the merge statement e.g.

```
merge dbo.table1 as target 
using (
        select 
            n.value('(SURVEY_ID)[1]', 'bigint') as surveyId
            ,n.value('(CLIENT_ID)[1]', 'int') as clientId
            ,n.value('(SERVICE)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [service]
            ,n.value('(RECDATE)[1]', 'datetime') as recieveDate
            ,n.value('(DISDATE)[1]', 'datetime') as dischargeDate
        from @xml.nodes('//DATA_EXPORT/SOMENODES') x(n)

        ) as source 
 on target.surveyId = source.surveyId
    and target.[service] = source.[service]
 when matched then 
 update set 
        target.clientId = source.clientId,
        target.[service] = source.[service],
        target.surveyRecieveDate = source.recieveDate,
        target.dischargeDate = source.dischargeDate
when not matched then
insert (surveyId, clientId, [service], surveyRecieveDate, dischargeDate)
values (surveyId, clientId, [service], recieveDate, dischargeDate)
option (optimize for unknown);
```

Comment: Glad you fixed the first issue. I have executed your `MERGE` statement and it worked for me with no modification (on `SQL Server 2008 R2`).

Comment: @danradu: yeah it was corrected version of merge statement. I was using option keyword inside the merge earlier which should not be done in any case.